# Errors in inline assembly in VC++ 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, assembly, x86

I'm trying to create some inline assembly in VC++ 2010 to unpack a RGB buffer of byte into a RGBA buffer of bytes, here's what I've come up with:

But I get the error

```
1>c:\users\tom\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\source\engine\image_load.c(28):     error C2414: illegal number of operands
1>c:\users\tom\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\source\engine\image_load.c(28):     error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'first operand'; found ':'
1>c:\users\tom\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\source\engine\image_load.c(29):     error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found ':'
1>c:\users\tom\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\source\engine\image_load.c(29):     warning C4405: 'MOV' : identifier is reserved word
1>c:\users\tom\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\source\engine\image_load.c(30):     error C2415: improper operand type
1>c:\users\tom\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\source\engine\image_load.c(31):     error C2415: improper operand type
1>c:\users\tom\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\source\engine\image_load.c(37): warning C4405: 'loop' : identifier is reserved word
1>c:\users\tom\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\source\engine\image_load.c(71): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
```

I'm not really sure what's wrong with it, this is my code:

```
void RGBtoRGBA (byte *rgba, const byte *rgb, int pixelCount) {
    __asm { 
        MOV EDX, pixelCount
        MOV EBX, rgba
        MOV ECX, rgb
        loop:
            MOV [EBX], ECX
            MOV [EBX+1], [ECX+1]
            MOV [EBX+2], [ECX+2] 
            MOV [EBX+3], 255
            ADD EBX, 4
            ADD ECX, 3
            DEC EDX
            JNZ loop
    }
}
```

Forgive me, I'm new to assembly :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No general-purpose instruction supports 2 memory operands like you wrote:

```
MOV [EBX+1], [ECX+1]
MOV [EBX+2], [ECX+2]
```

General-purpose instructions typically can only have these 2 operand combinations:

- register + constant
- register + memory
- register + register
- memory + constant

You'll have to rewrite your code to use valid operand combinations. Start reading the CPU manual about the details of instructions.

Also, `loop` is an instruction name. You shouldn't use it for label names.